# htaccess displaying content from index regardless of conditions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the htaccess content

```
php_flag opcache.enable Off

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on


#redirect from "/search.php?mc=123" to "master-123"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search.php\?mc=([^&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ master-%1? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^master-([^./]+)/?$ ?mc=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

If I remove the content from the htaccess file the products load properly, if I add the rewrite rules it loads the page properly (from the console) but shows index.php content

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^ /master-%1? [R=301,L,NE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on    

#redirect from "/search.php?mc=123" to "master-123"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?mc=([^&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /master-%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^master-([^./]+)/?$ search.php?mc=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```